# Accented characters on Emacs

Tags: emacs

When I type an accented character (eg ñ, ç, ã), it doesn't self-insert immediately, but rather displays itself on the minibuffer as if it was a prefix key (eg ç -> ç-). Is there a way to change this behavior? I can't even capture it with <f1>kç to find out what is happening.

Thanks!

Comment: which version of emacs are you using ? What is the language of your machine or your emacs env (you can get info with M-x mule-diag) ? I'm typing with a french keyboad and I don't get problems with ç, so it should be possible to fix that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the problem emacs' starter kit, with the binding `(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)`

Answer (score 24):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>

What this will do is display a *help* window with all of the key sequences for accented characters which are currently available to you.

For example:

```
Key     binding

C-x 8 <     «

C-x 8 =     ¯

C-x 8 >     »

C-x 8 ?     ¿

C-x 8 C     ©

C-x 8 L     £

C-x 8 P     ¶
```

Comment: +1 didn't know about this.  Note that if you have remapped `help-char` (as I have), then you can type that char (`h` by default) after any prefix (such as `C-x v` for `vc-mode`) to get a list of the bindings.  Nice!

Answer (score 6):

Do the [Emacswiki internationalization pages](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryInternationalization) help?  How about the advice in [language environment](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LanguageEnvironment)?

*Edit:* See [input methods](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InputMethods) -- and in a new buffer, I can do

- M-x set-input-method to 'latin-1-prefix' (which also TAB-completes) and you get
- Umlaute äöüÄÖÜ  (¨ followed by vowel)
- Sharp-s ß  (¨ followed by s)
- Accents éèô (fwd or backtick or ^ followed by vowel)

and they all display fine.