# How to configure emacs to compose characters?

Tags: emacs, unicode, hotkeys

I want my emacs to globally replace

```
:>>:
```

with

```
»
```

during typing. Any other typing combination is ok, too. I just chose `:`...`:` because that made it easier for emacs to descern the "name" of the replacement. I have a couple of sequences I want to be replaced in this way, i.e.

```
:>>:    with   »
:<<:    with   «
:e/:    with   e-accent-acute
:e\:    with   e-accent-grave
```

and so on.

Maybe there is a mechanism in emacs I can use. But googling did not get anything useful, I probably did not use the right search terms.

One big issue seems to be that the `»` in question is a unicode char and the `.emacs`-file has problems with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs supports many *Input Methods* ([doc here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Input-Methods.html)).

For example, with the `latin-1-prefix` input method, you can type <kbd>`e</kbd> to get the grave accented e; <kbd>~<</kbd> will give you the opening guillemet.

Call `set-input-method` and select `latin-1-prefix` for this.

The function `describe-input-method` will show you complete help for your current input method.

Another interesting input method is `TeX`, which substitutes TeX symbols on the fly, such as `\Delta`, `^1`, `~n`, etc.

Answer to related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2030840/605276). Nice tutorials [here](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2010/10/13/diacritics-in-emacs/) or [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InputMethods).

Comment: `C-x 8 c-h` from [here](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2010/10/13/diacritics-in-emacs/) did the trick! with that list I discovered that `C-x 8 <` already inserts `«` for me. No need to change anything, only to learn the existing key sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Abbrev Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AbbrevMode). Set `:>>:` to map to `»` etc.. The mode will automatically substitute. To do this, edit the abbrev file to include your mapping, or simply create the mapping in Emacs and save it with `M-x write-abbrev-file`.

p.s. I *think* Emacs is Unicode safe ATM. I've been using various Unicode characters for a long time.

Comment: Good idea. i use `dabbrev-mode` anyway. I have to try out how these work together.